# Change cocoa word completions system-wide - possible?

Tags: cocoa, nstextview, macos

In your own app modifying the word completions from NNTextView is as simple as implementing textView:completions:forPartialWordRange:indexOfSelectedItem:

Is there any way to do tjis for other apps, that is replacing or augmenting the built-in word completion suggestions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, to some extent. You need to write a *spell server*. Once installed, you can select the default spell checker in the system preferences. For documentation, see [Apple's introduction](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/SpellCheck/SpellCheck.html) and detailed references, e.g. for [`NSSpellServer`](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSSpellServer_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000379).

However, I don't think you can implement everything in your own spell server what Apple's standard spell/grammar checker does; compare the list of methods `NSSpellServer` needs to implement, and methods [`NSSpellChecker`](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSSpellChecker_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000378) has. Apple slowly adds to `NSSpellServer` the methods which correspond to those of `NSSpellChecker`... let's hope Apple does this quickly.

Comment: Hi Yuri, great answer thanks. Skimming the docs it doesn't exactly seem like something you can sell via the App Store. What would your guess be?

Comment: I have no idea. Please try and tell us how it goes! At least in Japan a few companies sell their own input servers, but I haven't seen any on the Mac App Store.

Comment: Will do. I am terribly sorry that I misspelled your name. I am mortified. My only excuse: I grew up with a close friend who had a brother named Yuri...

Comment: No problem, Yuri is also a nice name:)